# Image viewer that lets you freeze rows and columns?

Tags: image-viewer, genealogy

I'm doing genealogical research and looking at scanned graphics of old censuses.  It is tabulated data, much like a large Excel spreadsheet.  If I were actually using Excel, I could [freeze header rows and columns](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/17), and scroll the data around, always seeing what an individual cell refers to.

Is there any image viewer that lets me do this -- freeze a certain number of rows and columns of pixels and scan around the rest of the image?  (I can think of other nifty features that'd be useful for such a thing, but this is my primary need).

(My preference would be something that runs under OS X 10.10, but that isn't a requirement.  Free/open-source is also nice, but not required.)

Comment: Can you import the tabulated data into a spreadsheet program somehow? I think that would be a better approach.

Comment: Not that I can see.  When I put the graphic (the last one I downloaded is 4280x3144 pixels) into Apple Numbers (I don't actually have Excel on this computer), it made it really tiny to fit into a single cell.  I wouldn't have been surprised if it showed it at original size, but I don't think it would let me put it in the header and scroll part of it.  (Neat idea, though.)

Comment: Depending on the size of the text for the area in question, how about using an OCR program (print or screen reader) to convert to text? Then do some formatting (depending on how well the OCR program does that) and import into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @user3169, it would have to be an amazingly impressive OCR program.  I have a hard time reading the scanned censuses; they aren't clear, with solid black on pure white, the handwriting is sometimes hard to decipher, etc ...